# SELECT STATEMENT WITH ORDER BY

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, inner-join

I have a simple select statement with joins in oracle I have one agregate function like sum(COLUMN) , my query works fine and it return the result , Now I am adding one-two more columns from same table to which I have a join , I am requiring simple column values no agregate function when I add first column it ask me that it needed to be in group by as it is not agregate function I did that , but after doing that i am getting more number of rows which i were getting previously what could be the reason, when I add one more columns than again number of rows increased like with my first query without adding these two columns the result was 544 and now it is 766

```
select distinct 'carTypes' as type, mi.WOMENNAME as "mother name", mi.womencnic as "mother CNIC", '' as BFORMNO, '' as child_gender, mi.PROVINCE, mi.district, mi.tehsil, mi.HUSBANDNAME, mi.PHONENO contact, mi.address, SUM(p.amount) paid_amount

from MINFORMATION mi

inner join PAYMENTINFORMATION p on p.BENEFICIARYID=mi.WOMENID and p.BANKSTATUS='Successfull'

where mi.month IS NOT NULL


and p.generationdate between '24-JUN-21' and '01-JAN-22'

group by  mi.WOMENNAME, mi.womencnic,mi.PROVINCE, mi.district, mi.tehsil, mi.HUSBANDNAME, mi.PHONENO , mi.address
```

above is my query

Answer (score 0):

That's how it goes. When there's an aggregate function in the `select` column list all non-aggregated columns must be included in the `group by` clause (`group by`, not `order by` as your title suggests; `order by` is irrelevant in this matter).

For example, as of Scott's `emp` table: if you want to compute sum of salaries, the result is only one row:

```
SQL> select sum(sal)
  2  from emp;

  SUM(SAL)
----------
     29025
```

If you add `deptno` column, it means you want to compute sum of salaries per each department. As there are employees from 3 departments, it results in 3 rows:

```
SQL> select deptno, sum(sal)
  2  from emp
  3  group by deptno;

    DEPTNO   SUM(SAL)
---------- ----------
        30       9400
        20      10875
        10       8750
```

Adding yet another column - `job` - means that you want to calculate sum of salaries per each department, and per each job within that department; all that increases number of resulting rows:

```
SQL> select deptno, job, sum(sal)
  2  from emp
  3  group by deptno, job
  4  order by deptno, job;

    DEPTNO JOB         SUM(SAL)
---------- --------- ----------
        10 CLERK           1300
        10 MANAGER         2450
        10 PRESIDENT       5000
        20 ANALYST         6000
        20 CLERK           1900
        20 MANAGER         2975
        30 CLERK            950
        30 MANAGER         2850
        30 SALESMAN        5600

9 rows selected.
```

---

Therefore, what kind of output would you want to get? If you could explain it, maybe we could suggest approach that would make it happen.

Comment: Littlefoot thanks for detail answer, basically you explained well but that is not the case with my issue I am having 620 Rows when I am simply running my existing query , my query is not having any aggregate function 
It returns 620 rows but I have been asked to add two more columns one is generation date when I add it the number of rows increased.

Comment: If *nothing else* changed in query, then number of rows doesn't change no matter how many columns you add to SELECT column list. It *would* change if someone else, in another session, added any number of rows and committed, and those rows were selected due to WHERE clause in your query. Other than that, no.

Comment: Yet another thing: if there are no aggregates in SELECT, what's the purpose of the GROUP BY clause? Remove it. If you want to get a **distinct** row set, then use SELECT DISTINCT instead. GROUP by *will* produce the same result, but brings confusion.

Comment: Littlefoot Thanks for the detail reply I have no agregate function previously I was taking agregate like sum(amount) but at the time I have no installment column and I was getting total like 4000 as sum(amount) but now I add installment column separately so I am not taking sum as 4000 has been paid with two installment one and installment two, your above example is fine i understood but remember you sum(Sal) is same but in my case Sum(SAL) is getting greater by adding each additional column